# Resistance and energy cost in an AC circuit

Tags: ac, resistance, amperage

I’m learning on my own about EE concepts. According to Ohm's law if voltage is constant then current and resistance will affect each other primarily. I believe most household AC circuits provide roughly constant voltage (110 V - 120 V).

So pretend my appliance is 1 amp. That means I would need a lot of resistance to prevent my appliance from exploding. Resistors convert energy to heat.

So if something is plugged into an outlet, regardless of its amperage requirements, is the electrical usage the same? Either it’s being used by the appliance or burned off in heat? How do resistors handle that level of heat?

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about the job of a resistor. Could you explain in detail your understanding of how this all works?

Comment: attack, This sounds almost as though you imagine you are working against the power of a tidal wave, where you either dissipate (waste) or use (for practical things) its power. If power plugs delivered a fixed power to devices hooked to the prongs, we'd all have a problem. Luckily, that's not the situation. The plugs provide access to a voltage. One arranges an electrical system so that it efficiently *sips* at this voltage, taking only what it needs to take. What it does take, all of it is burned off either as heat or as useful work or both, with the goal being more useful work and less heat.

Comment: there are no resistors that prevent an appliance from "exploding"

Comment: Thanks. Jonk - where does the unsipped power go? Through neutral and back to the grid to be recycled back to the customers?

Comment: Jsotola I was being hyperbolic. But if too much current is supplied it is typically bad for an appliance

Comment: Hearth, My understanding is that a resistor reduces current but as a by-product emits that energy as heat. If a device needs low current there would have to be high resistance.

Comment: If your load consumes 1A then as long as the supply can provide 1A then all is ok. The supply might be able to provide a zillion Amps, but the 1A load will only consume 1A. For your load to consume 1A, then it’s effective resistance is 120Ohms (assuming 120Vac).  If your load is an incandescent lamp, then some of the energy will be wasted as heat and some to provide the light. Hopefully most of the energy goes to providing useful work like turning a fan etc.

Comment: You'll probably like the answers you get a lot better if you explain why all things should have the same electrical consumption.  This does not follow at all from anything else you've said, so clearly we are all missing something you are assuming.  Without knowing what that thing is you aren't going to get a completely satisfying answer.

Comment: @attackofthemike That's the problem with the way you are thinking about this. There is no unsipped power to return. Let's switch analogies. Imagine a setup for air tools. Power in this context is similar to PSI multiplied by the gallons of air a tool requires per second. When your air compressor is fully charged up, it can supply a certain PSI to any nozzle or tool. But the tool determines how much air it requires per second. And there is nothing to "return." If a tool uses a lot of air per second then your compressor just has to turn on more often to keep the tank's PSI the same.

Comment: @attackofthemike PSI is like voltage and gallons per second is like amps. Different air tools, all designed for the same PSI (voltage), will use different amounts of air per second (current.) The air compressor doesn't shove more air than a tool needs. It can't. The tool "sips" the air it needs and the compressor maintains the PSI in the tank. Some tools require a lot of air (orbital sander) and some tools require almost none (stapler), per second. But the tool *allows* air and it's the combination of PSI and the air required per second that decides the power consumed.

Comment: @attackofthemike The place where this analogy really fails is that electronics plays with charges (electrons, mostly.) It turns out that only a few of them could be used to move the moon away from the Earth. Just a small accumulation of them is all you need to create unimaginable forces. So electronics is *forced* to use two wires, not one (for example a hose for air.) The reason is that the charges have to be put back to where they came from or else we'd destroy the entire universe! So two wires allow the charges to circulate and everywhere maintain the balance of those leaving and arriving.

Answer (score 2):

A 120V appliance that is limited to 1 Amp has to have an internal resistance of 120 ohms, and would thus dissipate (use) 120W.

(We'll set aside AC vs. DC for the moment. For our purpose here - resistive loads - it doesn't matter.)

That is:

- Resistance(appliance) = 120V / 1A = **120 Ohms** (Ohm's Law R = E / I)
- Power(appliance) = 120V * 1A = **120 Watts** (Ohm's Law P = E * I)

Where does the appliance 'use' that power? By doing some sort of work, such emitting light, spinning a motor, charging a battery, making heat, or some other use of energy.

Where does the electricity 'go'? It flows in and out of the circuit as a loop. In fact, at 1A, one **Coulomb** of charge per second flows in that loop. It enters at high electromotive potential (120V), and exits at lower potential (0V), giving up energy (120W) in the process. But it's still one Coulomb in and one Coulomb out.

(What's a Coulomb? It's a quantity of electron charges, 6.24 * 10^18 of them.)

Think of the water analogy. Voltage is like pressure, current is like volume. Now consider a closed pressure system running a turbine. The water (charge) flows in at high pressure (voltage), does work in the turbine (resistive load), then flows back out at lower pressure (voltage.) Yet, the water volume (current) is the same going in as going out, and throughout the whole loop.

This same-in, same-out, same-everywhere electrical flow of is known as Kirchhoff's Current Law. No electrons are lost, they just move from a higher potential to a lower one, and give off energy wherever they do work (encounter resistance.)

Now consider a loop with no resistance at all. It could conduct infinite current and give off no energy, but it also can't have any voltage difference at all. Superconductors come very close to this. In fact, a superconducting loop (like an MRI magnet) can have a current circulating in it nearly forever. Such loops have even been studied as a means to store energy, like perfect flywheels.